# Minimum distance between two access points on the same channel?

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, wifi-transfer

Looking for the answer, I read many of the Q&A posted here, so I could get an idea on how to separate access points over a certain area. But most of the answers deal with a "optimum distance" or "maximum distance" and couldn't find the answer or clues to my question, which is:

Is there a recommendation for a minimum distance when placing two access points?

**IMPORTANT**:
Rather than a solution to the real situation (there are many possible ones), my question is intended so I can understand the interference at the physical level.

Some extra information:

- The actual situaion is that there are 4 access points in a space of 5m x 5m (16x16 ft.)
- The access points need to be all on the same channel.
- I can't set the Tx power on them (auto-regulated, no setting)
- It's a Linksys access point (WAP300n) and I couldn't find Tx power specs
- They need to be at the same height level.

The idea is to connect 2 devices per AP, and give the same bandwidth to each AP.
I can only use 2 of the walls of the room.
Behind the wall there are 2 APs I cant move, and this APs(behind the wall) are on the corners, this means my APs ended up being close to each other.

I know I could solve this situation in many other ways. But I would really like to understand how signals interact when put close together, and how the AP's react to this situation.

And most important, there is no budget to buy new hardware.

Thanks again.

Comment: Why bother evenly spreading the clients per AP if everything is on the same channel in the same 5m x 5m room? The channel will be your bottleneck, not your AP hardware.

Comment: Captain @Spiff, I'll edit the question to be more accurate of what I'm trying to achieve. And thank you for the correcting the question. It looks better now.

Comment: Your edits still don't explain why you're trying to jam so many same-channel APs into this area. If you've already got two APs just outside the room, why not just use those instead of adding more? If your goal is to maximize per-client bandwidth, you're doing it wrong. If you have some other goal, you should tell us so we can help you optimize for your real goal. This feels like a major "X-Y Problem" going on here.

Comment: The goal is to avoid colliding with the apartments that are next door, on both sides.
So ideally, Apartment #1 would be on channel 1, Apt #2  on channel 6, and Apt #3 on channel 11. 

The other option would be to draw an AP grid,  split the whole grid in different channels, and assign channels to each AP of the neighbors. But  this would require more coordination with 3rd parties, and still, because of short distance there would be some interference.

Comment: So why not just put one AP in the middle of the space?

Comment: Rather than a solution to the real situation (there are many possible ones), my question is intended so I can understand the interference at the physical level. I was also hoping someone could find out what the specs are for this access points (wap300n) to help me do some math about the interference and distance.

A more simple approach to my question would be:
Is 1mt. apart same as 3 mts. or 5 mts.

Thank you all very much for taking your time to answer

Comment: The minimum recommended distance is just another way to say, *the optimal distance.* (The maximum (and best) distance would, of course, be infinity; anything smaller than the optimal distance would not be recommended.)

Comment: @docliving Regarding wave interference patterns, not sure how helpful this would be, [but it's entertaining.](https://phet.colorado.edu/en/simulation/wave-interference). With high enough frequency and amplitude, and "two drips," the graphic shows that the signals cancel each other out in about half of the area (the black parts).

Comment: @jpaugh Thank you very much for contributing. I'm still hoping to improve the answer with more comments exactly like yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance between the APs of 1, 3 and 6 feet will all behave the same. Those distances are in very close proximity of each other.

Avoid configuring your AP's on the same channel at all costs in such a small space! It creates collisions of packets and interference.  In such a small space, it doesn't matter how low you set your transmit power, you'll still get overlap.  So, I would use channels 1, 6 and 11 OR I would make the move to 5GHz, where I have lots more channels to pick from.

Comment: I'm interested in the interference part. 
Calculating db against distance. 
something like: 0.5 mts is the same as 1.5mts is the same. 
or less than feet if creates  electromagnetic interference.

Comment: @docliving - I don't know mts, but I can tell you that it's a fine balance between transmit power (how far you can transmit) and receive threshold/sensitivity (how far can you listen).  Both those knobs can be tweaked to achieve optimal air quality.  In your case, because your AP's are so close, it will be impossible to dial the power and rx threshold so far down that it will not cause interference.  At one point, if you go too low, you may cause distortion at the PAs.

Comment: @docliving - There's a good article on Single Channel Architecture VS Multi Channel Architecture at https://praveenkumar4blog.wordpress.com/2017/05/01/single-channel-architecture-vs-multi-channel-architecture/

Comment: @docliving - A company called Meru Networks attempted Single Channel Architecture, but it failed.

Comment: As for the AP's, the problem get complicated because the Linksys WAP300n don't have Tx power settings, so I have no control at all on transmit  power.

Comment: @docliving - Unfortunately, that will be a problem.  I don't know your budget, but you will be better off if you bye Enterprise level Access Points - Those will give you the knobs you need.

Comment: So for the actual AP's, in terms of distance do you think is the same 1 feet than 3 feet than 6 feet? Assuming they will auto adjust the transmit power

Comment: Yes - The distance between the APs of 1, 3 and 6 feet will all behave the same.  Those distances are in very close proximity of each other.  You may be able to reduce noise and interference if you select different channels, but that too is kind of iffy.